# Azure WebJob calling WebAPI on same host

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-webjobs

I have a WebJob which calls API endpoints on the same host. As per samples on I've gathered the HttpClient requires the complete URL and the host address is set through configuration. I want a mostly configuration-less setup and have the webjob calling the localhost. Is it possible to use:

- https://localhost?
- Figure out the server url by looking at the host details?
- Skip the host address and use relative paths?

Thanks!

ÉB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use localhost or relative path.

Instead, to get the host name, you can rely on the `WEBSITE_HOSTNAME` environment variable, which is set to `YourSite.azurewebsites.net`.